# Proving $3 + (x+y+z)(\frac{1}{x}+\frac{1}{y}+\frac{1}{z}) \ge 6$

Tags: inequality

I have the given inequality

$$\dfrac {x+y+y+z}{x+y+y+z-x-z}+\dfrac {x+y+x+z}{x+y-z-y+x+z}+\dfrac {y+z+z+x}{-x-y+y+z+z+x}\ge 6$$

we we rewrite to

$$\dfrac {2x+y+z}{x}+\dfrac {2y+x+z}{y}+\dfrac {2z+x+y}{z}\ge 12$$
Since

$$\dfrac {2x+y+z}{2x}= \frac{x+y+z}{x}+1=\frac{y/2}{x} + \frac{z/2 }{x} + 1,$$

$$\dfrac {2y+x+z}{2y}=\frac{x/2}{y}+ \frac{z/2}{y}+ 1,$$

$$\dfrac {2z+x+y}{2z}=\frac{x/2}{z} + \frac{y/2}{z} + 1$$

This gives by AH-HM inequality:

$$(x+y+z)(1/x + 1/y + 1/z) + 3$$

But how can I prove using this that

$$3 + (x+y+z)(\frac{1}{x}+\frac{1}{y}+\frac{1}{z}) \ge  6$$

But how do I prove this?

Thanks

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/78406/42969

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$3 + (x+y+z)(\frac{1}{x}+\frac{1}{y}+\frac{1}{z}) \ge  6$ is not true. Simply try $(x, y, z)=(1,1,1)$ suffices.

If your intended question is proving $3 + (x+y+z)(\frac{1}{x}+\frac{1}{y}+\frac{1}{z}) \ge  12$, here's the proof:
$$\begin{align}
&3+(x+y+z)(\frac{1}{x}+\frac{1}{y}+\frac{1}{z}) \\
&\geq3+(1+1+1)^2 &\text{by Cauchy-Schwarz} \\
&=12
\end{align}$$